# Python "list order"

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 troubles with my data, can anyone help me:

How can I get from this:

**1.**

```
k=[['1','7', 'U1'],
 ['1.5', '8', 'U1'],
 ['2', '5.5', 'U1']]
```

get this

```
1,7,U1
1.5,8,U1
2,5.5,U1
```

---

**EDIT 2   I MAKE SOME CHANGE ON  second case:, still searching solution for this one:**

**2.** And how to get, from this

```
l=array([[[ 4.24231542], 'U1'],
       [[ 3.41424819], 'U1'],
       [[ 2.17214734], 'U1'],], dtype=object)
```

get

```
4.24231542,U1
3.41424819,U1
2.17214734,U1
```

Thanks

Comment: Neither of those are syntactically valid.

Comment: Hmm, this is what I get on Python Shell, I just copy some of data...maybe I must add commas ?

Comment: Yes, the commas are definitely required.

Comment: Hmm I added for first example, did you know how to copy from IDE exactly with commas and everything..?

Comment: I see you've changed the question. Is that a NumPy `array`? If so, what is `U1`?

Comment: Yes it's nummpy array, U1....is just name of class; I received this in my output(without commas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1)

```
for x in k:
    print(','.join(x))
```

2)

```
for x,y in l:
    print('%.8f,%s' % (x[0], y))
```

Comment: @thaking: how does it not do what you want? It produces exactly the output you specify.

Comment: How can I modify this to not print, to just save in new kk or ll?

Comment: Use a list comprehension: `[','.join(x) for x in k]`.

Comment: Hmmm, but then I get, when I print it : ['1,7,U1', '1.5,8,U1', '2,5.5,U1']

Comment: It's a list of lines without newlines. Add newlines and join them.

Answer (score 5):

One-line functional style:

```
print '\n'.join(','.join(x) for x in k)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for a,b,c in k: print "%s,%s,%s" % (a,b,c)

for a,b in l: print "%s,%s" % (a[0],b)
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I have also data where is not just 3(a,b,c), there is random data, for example 1,3.4,5,3.5,U1.....

Comment: @thaking: check any other of the gazillion here that uses `join`. They're all good for whatever length your data is.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> print k
[['1', '7', 'U1'], ['1.5', '8', 'U1'], ['2', '5.5', 'U1']]
>>> for a, b, c in k:
...     print '%s,%s,%s' % (a, b, c)
...
1,7,U1
1.5,8,U1
2,5.5,U1
```

Now, you try! (for the second one)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to venture a guess as to what you actually mean in terms of syntax

For the first one:

```
k=[['1','7', 'U1'],
 ['1.5', '8', 'U1'],
 ['2', '5.5', 'U1']]

for l in k:
    print ', '.join(l)
```

For the second one:

```
for l in k:
    print l[0][0], l[1]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The second will print the data space-separated, rather than comma-separated.

Answer (score 1):

```
for a in k: print ",".join (a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a single solution that will work for both **1** and **2**:

```
k = [['1', '7', 'U1'], ['1.5', '8', 'U1'], ['2', '5.5', 'U1']]
l = [[[4.2423154199999997], 'U1'], [[3.4142481899999999], 'U1'], [[2.17214734], 'U1']]

make_string = lambda x: ",".join(map(make_string, x)) if isinstance(x, list) else str(x)

print "\n".join(map(make_string, k))
print "\n".join(map(make_string, l))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using map:

```
k = [['1','7', 'U1'], ['1.5', '8', 'U1'], ['2', '5.5', 'U1']]

map(','.join, k) # returns ['1,7,U1', '1.5,8,U1', '2,5.5,U1']
```